runas cannot login samba ad
On a standalone (not domain join) Windows 11, I am trying to run:
runas /user:administrator@vms.local mmc.exe

But got following error:
Attempting to start mmc.exe as user "administrator@vms.local" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - mmc.exe
1326: The user name or password is incorrect.

However, /var/log/samba/log.samba shows NT_STATUS_OK:
[2024/08/10 23:33:24.175980,  3] ../../auth/auth_log.c:858(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [Kerberos KDC,ENC-TS Pre-authentication] user [(null)]\[administrator@vms.local] at [Sat, 10 Aug 2024 23:33:24.175961 EDT] with [aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [(null)] remote host [ipv4:192.168.8.239:50349] became [VMS]\[Administrator] [S-1-5-21-4177060000-1701195693-3506349788-500]. local host [NULL]
  {"timestamp": "2024-08-10T23:33:24.176045-0400", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 3}, "eventId": 4624, "logonId": "751e4ae975b6268c", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": null, "remoteAddress": "ipv4:192.168.8.239:50349", "serviceDescription": "Kerberos KDC", "authDescription": "ENC-TS Pre-authentication", "clientDomain": null, "clientAccount": "administrator@vms.local", "workstation": null, "becameAccount": "Administrator", "becameDomain": "VMS", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-4177060000-1701195693-3506349788-500", "mappedAccount": "Administrator", "mappedDomain": "VMS", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96", "clientPolicyAccessCheck": null, "serverPolicyAccessCheck": null, "duration": 19912}}
[2024/08/10 23:33:24.176240,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:90(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: heim_audit_vaddkv(): kv pair[0] elapsed=0.020076
[2024/08/10 23:33:24.176255,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:90(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ SUCCESS ipv4:192.168.8.239:50349 administrator@vms.local krbtgt/vms.local@vms.local pa=ENC-TS etype=18/18 canon_client_name=Administrator@VMS.LOCAL pac_attributes=1 pa-etype=18 client-pa=ENC-TS,128 end=1723383204 auth=1723347204 etypes=18,17,23,24,-135,3 renew=1723952004 pa-succeeded-kvno=1 reqaddrs=TYPE_20:57313150524f30312020202020202020 elapsed=0.020076 flags=renewable-ok,canonicalize,renewable,forwardable
[2024/08/10 23:33:24.176674,  3] ../../source4/samba/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'

Additionally, the user can connect to the domain controller in file explorer:

Anyone have clues?

Samba user list:
❯ samba-tool user list
ldb_wrap open of secrets.ldb
Guest
Administrator
test01
krbtgt


Can you get a list of the admin users on the Samba server? Does runas use logins from the Samba server?

@AndrewMorton Add the samba user list. And yes, I use "runas /user:administrator@vms.local". However, as the box is not domain joint, maybe that is the issue.

@Ramhound "administrator@vms.local" is the admin account in my Samba AD. There is no administrator account in my Win 11 machine.
